# dotLiquid Nested loop not working

Tags: c#, dotliquid

I have created a [dotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.com) template with two nested for loop

```
{% for item in page.Fields %}
        <li>
            {{ item.Name }}:
            <select>
                {% for list in item.ListValues %}
                    <option>{{ list.Text }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

With the following class:

```
public class Page: Drop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field : Drop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ListValue> ListValues { get; set; }
}

public class ListValue : Drop
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created an object and ran it like this:

```
page = MyPage; // This is the created object
Template template = Template.Parse(LiquidTemplate);
string output = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { page = this.page }));
```

The object is populated as:

```
new Page
        {
            Name = "My Page",
            Fields = new List<Field>
            {
                new Field
                {
                    Name = "Title",
                    ListValues = new List<ListValue>()
                },
                new Field
                {
                    Name = "Status",
                    ListValues = new List<ListValue>
                    {
                        new ListValue
                        {
                            Text = "Open"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

The inner for loop is not getting populated, even though the object is just fine. I see a lot of empty inner loop `<option>` tags...

I have just started with dotLiquid, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `IList<ListValue> ListValues`

Comment: Tried that and getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

This solution is from the developer of the dotliquid (I posted the same question on the issues list of the [github project](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/207))

dotliquid uses the [ruby convention](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-Drops#tips) by default.

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks a lot!!